# Get screenshot of incognito chrome in android

Tags: android, screenshot, incognito-mode

i am using `MediaprojectMannager API` to get screenshot of android device. The problem here is i can't get screenshot when chrome is in incognito mode of chrome. I know this is due to chrome privacy policy and i can enable it in `chrome://flags` and continue with API in use. However is there any other way to get the screenshot without having to do it manually (automatically done by code) in this case? Thanks everyone!